# Refactoring two similar loops using a python function in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two similar for loops in Django that loops through a data model, while both loops are similar in nature they access different data models and different fields.  I'm having a difficult time trying to build a function and figuring out the proper arguments to pass within the functions that accommodates both loops.  Please see the loops below.

```
#Loop 1:

task_list = []
toQuery = group1.task.all()
for x in toQuery:
    array = []
    array.append(x.id)
    array.append(x.task_name)
    task_list.append(array)

#Loop 2:

student_list = []
toQuery2 = student.task.all()
for x in toQuery2 :
    array = []
    array.append(x.id)
    array.append(x.student_name)
    task_list.append(array)
```

Comment: I assume that `for x in tasks` is actually `for x in toQuery` and `for x in toQuery2`?

Comment: For what you need a `toQuery`s variables?

Comment: Please update your post and make your question more clear. Post your models and the results expect !

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of looping, you can let the Django ORM do most of the work, with the [**`.values_list(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list) function, like:

```
task_list = list(group1.task.all().values_list('id', 'task_name'))
student_list = list(student.task.all().values_list('id', 'task_name'))
```

This will result in two lists containing 2-tuples. If you need lists as subelements, we can use an extra `map`ping:

```
# in case elements of the list need to be lists as well

task_list = list(map(list, group1.task.all().values_list('id', 'task_name')))
student_list = list(map(list, student.task.all().values_list('id', 'task_name')))
```

This not only makes the code more DRY, it also is more *declarative*: instead of writing *how* you want to do something, you write *what* you want.

The code will also be a bit faster, since the query will specify the columns we are interested in, and therefore the amount of data the database returns will usually be (a bit) smaller (of course it depends on the number of columns, and the size of the data stored in the columns we are *not* interested in).